# Extension of normal vector field to a domain

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, measure-theory, differential-calculus

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ be a bounded regular simply connected domain contained in a ball $S$. Assume also that $\Omega$ is simply connected by surfaces (i.e. every regular closed surface contained in $\Omega$ can be continuously deformed shrinking it to a point).

> Is it possible to define a $C^\infty(\overline{S \setminus \Omega})$ field of unit vectors that extends the external normal vectors to $\partial \Omega$ to the entire domain $\overline{S\setminus \Omega}$ ending, on the boundary $\partial S$ in the external normal vectors to $\partial S$?

Also, can we prove this under simpler/weaker assumptions too?

Comment: Do you mean a *ball* $S$?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Yes